# is there a way to add double quotes to fields splitted in two lines during parsing csv file through opencsv?

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I am getting a big production data in a csv file where some records are broken into two or more lines due to new line characters in the record. But the problem is that the field values that are broken into multiple lines are not enclosed in the double quotes.

I am parsing the file using OpenCSV API (using **readNext** method of **
com.opencsv.CSVReader**) in java. Do we have anything in OpenCSV or in any other API that identify the record split and enclose the splitted values in the record with double quotes, so that **readNext** method consider it as one record in-spite of new line character involved in the record.

Actually the point is, I don't want to write any complex logic to assemble the splitted records, as there can be column values for the record  that can be less than or equal to the header count in the file.

Comment: As you describe the situation, this does not sound to be solvable. The input you get is ambiguous.

Comment: Is there any chance your input has mixed line separators? If that's the case then check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35579847/csvparser-processes-lf-as-crlf/35604355#35604355